# How to dynamically allocate a 2d array and why?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, int

For my assignment one of the things I have to do in my program is dynamically allocate a 2D array.
I can't figure out how to do it or why.

This is what I have now.

```
   size = atoi(argv[1]);
   int Pond[size][size];
   int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < size; i ++){
      for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        Pond[i][j]=0;
      }
   }
```

I found a answer to do it this way but I can't figure out how to access each column or row.

```
int **Pond;
Pond = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Pond[i] = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct use of C's powerful array type syntax looks like this:

```
int (*Pond)[size] = malloc(size * sizeof(*Pond));
```

That's it for the allocation. After that, the elements in `Pond` can simply be accessed like this:

```
for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        Pond[y][x] = 0;
    }
}
```

And of course the deallocation:

```
free(Pond);
```

It doesn't get simpler.

Comment: +1 Note that this requires C99 compiler as `size` is not constant expression. If size is rather small, then even just `int Pond[size][size];` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution I was looking for. Could you tell me why I have to dynamically allocate though? So far the code works without malloc. The array won't change size in the program. It does pass the array to another function, is that why I need to malloc?

Comment: Sorry my comment went to the wrong post. It has been removes.

Comment: @Mike Dynamic allocation is something a good C programmer should have seen in all its forms, even if this tiny assignment doesn't use the flexibility of allocation, it may just be there to force you to use it a couple of times in the course. Most common reasons for using it are: 1. The variable you are putting data in has a very limited lifespan in the code (waste of space to have that memory always reserved). 2. The variable can change in size during the program's life time (you'd have to reserve a large overhead if you sized it statically).

Comment: @Asmyldof  One big reason `why` you would want to do this is if you try to create large arrays as stack based objects. The stack is often very limited in size (sometimes on the order of a megabyte or two). Try to create a large 2000 by 2000 array of ints (not defined  with the `static` attribute) inside a function. On most platforms it will likely fail at runtime because the stack will overflow.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Fair enough, I made the assumption the question meant "why didn't I do a global/static" witch on all compilers I use goes preferentially to heap. Anyway, you are right that it poses a danger of, if not breaking stack, severely cluttering it. Although I am going to try it on as many "factory-reset" systems to see what the end-score is next weekend :-)

Comment: Not your fault - I think the `why` in the question is ambiguous and open to interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` operator works on pointers pretty much the same way it works on array expressions, so you'd use `Pond[i][j]` to access a particular element regardless of how you allocate (unless you allocated it as a 1D array as dom0 shows).

If the number of rows and columns are known at compile time, this is the easiest:

```
#define M ... // rows
#define N ... // columns

int (*Pond)[N] = malloc ( sizeof *Pond * M);
...
Pond[i][j] = x;
...
free( Pond );
```

The *type* of the variable `Pond` is "pointer to `N`-element array of `int`".  The type of the *expression* `*Pond` is "N-element array of `int`".  So `sizeof *Pond` gives us the number of bytes in `N`-element array of `int`; we multiply this by `M` to get the total number of bytes required for the array.

Since `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)`, the `[]` operator works the same way on a pointer expression as it does on an array expression<sup>1</sup>; that is, you could use `Pond[i][j]` here as you would for a regular 2D array.

If the number of rows and columns are not known until run time, but you're using a C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that supports *variable length arrays*, it's pretty much the same:

```
size_t n, m;
/**
 * get values of n and m
 */
int (*Pond)[n] = malloc( sizeof *Pond * m );
...
Pond[i][j] = x;
...
free( Pond );
```

Same deal as above, it's just that `m` and `n` aren't known until runtime.  In both of these cases, the dynamically-allocated arrays are contiguous (all rows are adjacent in memory).

```
                +---+
          Pond: |   | ---+
                +---+    |
                 ...     |
                +---+    |
    Pond[0][0]: |   | <--+
                +---+
    Pond[0][1]: |   |
                +---+
                 ...
                +---+
  Pond[0][n-1]: |   |
                +---+
    Pond[1][0]: |   |
                +---+
    Pond[1][1]: |   |
                +---+
                 ...
                +---+
  Pond[m-1][0]: |   |
                +---+
  Pond[m-1][1]: |   |
                +---+
                 ...
                +---+
Pond[m-1][n-1]: |   |
                +---+
```

If the number of rows and columns aren't known until runtime, and you're using a compiler that does not support VLAs, you have two choices depending on whether you want the arrays to be contiguous or not.

If the array doesn't have to be contiguous, you can use a two-step allocation approach:

```
size_t n, m;
/**
 * get values for n and m
 */
int **Pond = malloc( sizeof *Pond * m ); // allocate m rows of pointer to int
if ( Pond )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
  {
    Pond[i] = malloc( sizeof *Pond[i] * n ); // allocate n columns of int for each row
  }
}
```

In this case, `Pond` is a pointer to pointer to `int`; it will wind up pointing to what is effectively a 1D array of pointers to `int`; each of those pointers will point to a 1D array of `int`, sort of like the following:

```
              +---+
        Pond: |   | ---+
              +---+    |
                       |
                +------+
                |
                V  
              +---+          
     Pond[0]: |   | ------------+ 
              +---+             |
     Pond[1]: |   | ---------+  |
              +---+          |  |
     Pond[2]: |   |          |  |  
              +---+          |  |
               ...           |  |
              +---+          |  |
   Pond[m-1]: |   |          |  | 
              +---+          |  |
                             |  |
              +---+          |  |
  Pond[0][0]: |   | <--------|--+
              +---+          |
  Pond[0][1]: |   |          |
              +---+          |
               ...           |
              +---+          |
Pond[0][n-1]: |   |          |
              +---+          |
                             |
              +---+          |
  Pond[1][0]: |   | <--------+
              +---+
  Pond[1][1]: |   |
              +---+
               ...
              +---+
Pond[1][n-1]: |   |
              +---+
```

But because `Pond[i][j]` is evaluated as `*(*(Pond + i) + j)`, it all still works.

Note that since this was a two-step allocation process, deallocation also requires two steps:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
  free( Pond[i] );
free( Pond );
```

If the array does need to be contiguous, then you'll have to allocate the memory as a 1D array and compute your indexes manually:

```
int *Pond = malloc( sizeof *Pond * m * n );
...
Pond[ i * m + j ] = x;
...
free( Pond );
```

---

<sup>1.  Under most circumstances, an array expression will be converted or "decay" to a pointer expression, so the subscript is actually working on a pointer expression either way.</sup>